# Creating a log of all pages visited by the user

Tags: python, django

I am creating this functionality with a Django application I have. I want to log all pages the user visits and display it to him.

I am using a middleware to achieve it.

```
class LoggingMiddleware:
    """
    Class used to register and fetch pages where the user has been visiting.
    """
    def process_template_response(self, request, response):

        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            UserHistory.objects.create(user=request.user, page_name=request.path, url=request.path)

            if response.context_data:
                response.context_data['user_history'] = UserHistory.objects.filter(user=request.user)

        return response
```

I want to name these UserHistory entries in the database, instead of just set the url as the name (as it i s now).
I have though of adding a variable to all views I have, in a way that the `request` object has something like `request.page_name`.

Can someone think of a better way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like you want cookies-- have you looked @ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: @Jeeves No, it was something else. I wanted to log all pages the user has been visiting and save it in the database. I managed to give every view I had a name and catch it with a `middleware`. Gave me some hours of hard work but it worked.